# Should each day's lifting target one muscle group or multiple muscle groups?

Tags: weightlifting

40 yr old male, been working out for a few years, generally decent fitness level. Not looking to get big, just looking to stay fit and have enough energy to chase my 2 year old around. I exercise about 4-5 times a week alternating between cardio and lifting, so I lift either 2 or 3 times a week.

My question is it better to target just one muscle group per day? So for example do maybe 4 sets of chest on Lift Day 1, 4 sets of arms on Lift Day 2, etc. Or, would it be better for the 4 sets to target different muscle groups, so Lift Day 1 maybe 1 set chest, 1 set back, 1 set arms, 1 set legs, etc. Then do the same on Lift Day 2 maybe vary the actual exercises.

Thanks.

Comment: If you do concentrate on one muscle group, it would be helpful if you work the antagonist muscle of that group. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Antagonist_(muscle)

Answer (score 2):

From everything I read, the question to ask yourself regarding doing a full body routine or split (focusing on various muscles during any one day's workout) is: Can I fully push/tax my various muscles in order to gain strength, size, etc. (dependent on your goals) at the same time OR do I need to focus on one major muscle group (chest, back, glutes/legs) at a time to get my results?

So, if you're happy with your progress with a full body routine, stay with it.  If you've maxed out your time/effort in a single workout and not seeing progress, either change what you're doing by adding weight or exercise or FOCUS (split).

Answer (score 2):

The answer to your question has to do with your personal goals.  Do you want to focus on strength or aesthetics?  There is a difference, both in programming and in the approach to training.

**Focus on Strength**

Check out an [Intro on Strength Training](http://ironstrong.org/index.php/topic/65-intro-to-strength-training/) I did a while back.  It provides some information what that entails.  The quick info as applies to your question is:

- Focus on compound lifts such as squats, bench press, deadlift, and overhead press
- Lower reps per set improve the top weight you can lift
- Programs are full body training of varying weights.

**Focus on Aesthetics**

This would be your bodybuilders.  The "ideal" body has your muscles in certain ratios to each other so that you achieve a balanced physique.  There's a couple distinctions between building muscle for strength and looks:

- Focus on isolation exercises to build mass where you want it, and not where you don't
- Higher reps per set improve sarcoplasmic hypertrophy (size)
- Programs tend to be split routines focusing on one muscle group at a time

**Jim Wendler's Twist**

Wendler was once a power lifter, and has devised a program (5/3/1) that can really be tailored to your end goals.  His program is designed for advanced lifters, meaning someone who can only make strength increases once a month.  However, there are some underlying philosophies that can be very useful depending on your current set of goals:

- Every successful program should have a strength component, a hypertrophy component (size), and a conditioning component.
- You simply vary the proportions of each to address your current goals; similar to the way you balance work, family, and play.
- Training sessions should be limited to about an hour.

**Conclusions**

Focus your training on what you want to do.  For me, I am concerned more with strength and conditioning, but I still need that hypertrophy component to help the support systems in my muscles to sustain the heavier lifts.

Comment: Can you please give references to Jim Wendlers programs. This makes a lot of sense. Add strength + size routines together, this would give very good results.

Comment: Check out http://www.jimwendler.com/ and the link to his book is http://www.amazon.com/Simplest-Effective-Training-Strength-Edition/dp/B00686OYGQ

Comment: If you just want to punch in numbers and get the program template for you check out http://www.strstd.com/